# Trying to transfer a file name to a different function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, file

I am writing code for class and I'm stuck on just one problem. I'm supposed to use the main function to call to a different function called 'file2list' which will take the file (that I brought from main) and convert it to a list. I have everything needed to create the list, I just can't get the file to run. (also I'm new to programming, so there can also be some silly errors)

This is in my main function

```
    #Call file2list
    vt=file2list('vt_municipalities.txt')
    nh=file2list('nh_municipalities.txt')
```

And then this is what my file2list function looks like

```
def file2list(muni_file):

    #Create lists
    muni_list=[]

    #Open files
    file=open('muni_file','r')
```

Basically, how can I bring the .txt file down to file2list? I get the error that muni_file doesn't exist. Thanks!

Comment: `muni_file` is a variable name while you pass it as a string literal to the `open` function. Just remove the quotes, i.e. `file = open(muni_file, 'r')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you are trying to open the file with the name `muni_file`, as you surrounded it with `'`, making it a string. To reference the variable that was passed into the function, remove the quotation marks (`'`) surrounding `muni_file`.

The `file=open` line should look something like this:

```
file=open(muni_file,'r')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it without quotes and it didn't work but I'm now realizing it was because of a different error. (I'm sorry, that was stupid). But really, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you are passing to `open()` a string that contains 'muni_file' as value, to use the parameter that you recieve, you should pass without `' '`